# Unable to install Hbase with Hadoop on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am new to `HBASE`, and while trying to install the same on `Ubuntu` system, I am facing some problem.

Below is the error log from `Zookeeper` log file

> 2014-01-18 06:10:51,392 WARN
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: caught end of stream
>   exception EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from
>   client sessionid 0x143a5b052980000, likely client has closed socket at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:220)
>   at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) 2014-01-18 06:10:51,394 INFO
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Closed socket connection
>   for client /127.0.0.1:56671 which had sessionid 0x143a5b052980000

Below is error log from master log:

> 2014-01-18 06:10:51,381 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session:
>   0x143a5b052980000 closed 2014-01-18 06:10:51,381 INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: HMaster main thread exiting
>   2014-01-18 06:10:51,381 ERROR
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine: Failed to start
>   master java.lang.RuntimeException: HMaster Aborted at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:160)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:104)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:76)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2120)

Please note, I am able to start `Hbase` successfully. I mean after starting `Hbase`, I am able to see `Hmaster` running using jps command. But as soon as I try to go to `Hbase` shell, this issue arises and then by executing jps command, I don't find `Hmaster` in list.

Please help me in this issue, as I tried to solve it by myself from last for days, but no luck. Please help.

Comment: what about Zookeeper ? is it running?

Comment: Looking in the zookeeper logs would also be helpful.

Comment: No zookeeper stopped running.

Comment: No zookeeper stopped running. Detailed log is 
org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x143ae8516780000 type:delete cxid:0xb zxid:0xba txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/backup-masters/localhost,60000,1390202397974 Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase/backup-masters/localhost,60000,1390202397974

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to check the configurations used in hbase-site.xml. When not properly configured, zookeeper might stop running and you will get such strange exceptions.